# Writing logs to a text file doesn't work

Tags: php

I have this code in /var/www/index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chipperyman573</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/fav.ico" />
</head>
<body>
I honestly don't know what you expected.
</body>
</html>

<?php
//get visitors ip address
$ipaddress = $REMOTE_ADDR;
//get visit date
$vdate = date("m-d-y");
//UserAgent
$agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
//Set whole string
$str = $ipaddress.." visited on "..$vdate.." using user agent "..$agent..".";
//Set log name
$fi = "/logs/mainLog.txt";
file_put_contents($fi, $str);
?>
```

I have made a text file called mainLog.txt in /logs however after visiting `chipperyman573.com` in my browser nothing appears there. All files (the /index.php, /logs and /logs/mainLog.txt all have 777 file perms).

Why, and how do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration problem.

Comment: Why the double dots?
//Set whole string
$str = $ipaddress.." visited on "..$vdate.." using user agent "..$agent..".";

Comment: Fix the double dots issu mentionned by dibs and change fi for "logs/mainLog.txt".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is possibly here

```
$fi = "/logs/mainLog.txt";
```

In Linux, `/` is the root of the server. So it's looking in the root for your log file (which you probably don't have permissions to access). Instead, try making your path relative to your file, or include the full correct path

```
$fi = "./logs/mainLog.txt";
```

Comment: No the page displays fine. The text file is empty

Comment: Tried echoing `getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$fi = "/logs/mainLog.txt";
```

to

```
$fi = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/mainLog.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in linux/UNIX based environments, a / at the beginning of a file path tells the computer to go from the root directory. 
Take the / out and it should work.